# C++ template function build error: could not deduce template argument for '<unnamed-symbol>'

Tags: templates, visual-c++

I have a template function overloading code which compiles with C++14 and C++17 standard. But it doesn't pass the compiler with C++20 standard. Could someone help me to identify how to resolve the build error? The template overloading functions are:

**Overload function 1**:

```
template<size_t I, UCHAR Operator, class T, class = std::enable_if_t<Operator == SQL_COMP_OP_IN || Operator == SQL_COMP_OP_NOT_IN>>
auto _add_sql_where_op_str(CIT2String& strSqlStatement, T&& select, typename base_t::template overload_priority<0>)
  -> std::void_t<decltype(std::size(std::forward<T>(select)))
               , decltype(std::begin(std::forward<T>(select)))
               , decltype(std::end(std::forward<T>(select)))
               , decltype(std::begin(std::forward<T>(select)) != std::end(std::forward<T>(select)))
                >
  {
  CIT2String ins((ULONG)std::size(std::forward<T>(select)) * 20);
  CIT2String in(20);
  ins += '(';
  bool fFirst = true;
  for (auto&& elem : std::forward<T>(select))
    {
    static_assert(can_make_du<field_t<I>, decltype(elem)>::value, "TableSerialiser: Elements of iterable range are of incorrect type.");

    if (!fFirst)
      ins += ',';
    else
      fFirst = false;

    SelStrMakeFieldData(this->fldinfo_t::dwFieldIDs[I],
                        in.GetPointer(),
                        make_du<field_t<I>>(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem)).GetPointer());
    ins += in;
    }
  ins += ')';

  strSqlStatement.GetString() = SelStrAddConditionForField(strSqlStatement.GetString(),
                                                           this->fldinfo_t::dwFieldIDs[I],
                                                           Operator,
                                                           SQL_COMP_OP_TYPE_LITERAL,
                                                           ins.GetPointer());
  }
```

**Overload function 2**:

```
template<size_t I, UCHAR Operator, class T, class = std::enable_if_t<Operator == SQL_COMP_OP_IN || Operator == SQL_COMP_OP_NOT_IN>>
void _add_sql_where_op_str(CIT2String& strSqlStatement, T&& select, typename base_t::template overload_priority<1>)
  {
  if constexpr (Operator == SQL_COMP_OP_IN)
    static_assert(false, "TableSerialiser: Select using in operator must be an iterable range.");
  else
    static_assert(false, "TableSerialiser: Select using not-in operator must be an iterable range.");
  }
```

**Overload function 3**:

```
template<size_t I, UCHAR Operator, class T, class = std::enable_if_t<Operator != SQL_COMP_OP_IN && Operator != SQL_COMP_OP_NOT_IN>, void* = 0>
void _add_sql_where_op_str(CIT2String& strSqlStatement, T&& select, typename base_t::template overload_priority<0>)
  {
  static_assert(can_make_du<field_t<I>, T&&>::value, "TableSerialiser: Select is of incorrect type.");

  strSqlStatement.GetString() = SelStrAddConditionForField(strSqlStatement.GetString(),
                                                           TableInfos<TableID>::field_infos::dwFieldIDs[I],
                                                           Operator,
                                                           SQL_COMP_OP_TYPE_AUTOMATIC,
                                                           make_du<field_t<I>>(std::forward<T>(select)).GetPointer());
  }
```

The calling code is:

```
template<size_t I, UCHAR Operator, class T>
void _add_sql_where_or_str(CIT2String& strSqlStatement, bool& fFirst, T&& select)
  {
  if (!fFirst)
    strSqlStatement += " OR ";
  else
    fFirst = false;

  _add_sql_where_op_str<I, Operator>(strSqlStatement, std::forward<T>(select), typename base_t::template priority_tag({}));
  }
```

but the compiler report build errors on the line calling function
**_add_sql_where_op_str**
_add_sql_where_op_str': no matching overloaded function found

also another error is:
could not deduce template argument for '<unnamed-symbol>'

If some C++ expert in template could help, that would be great. Thanks

I tried with the calling function as

_add_sql_where_op_str<I, Operator>(strSqlStatement, std::forward(select), priority_tag{});

it doesn't work, but this used to build.

Comment: You might consider tagging this C++ for a larger audience and putting together a [mcve] that can be compiled to see the full error messages.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but `typename base_t::template overload_priority<0>`, where
does `base_t` defined?